# Export and import data from one object to other within salesforce automatically

Tags: apex, visualforce, scheduled-apex

There are 2 objects in salesforce. object A and object B. Data (1000's of  records) in object A is inserted by integration process(fetching from external system and inserting in salesforce object directly). Now we need to fetch the data from object A and import it in Object B automatically.

What are recommended options for doing this?

Comment: I you don't need the data in Real time, then in my opinion  scheduling a batch apex is best way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Lightning process builder which will create a record of object B using Object A.
In case you want to do this operation on already existing data in Salesforce. 
Just user following code in developer console.

```
List<api-name-of-object-A> object_A_List = [SELECT Id, Name,........(all the fields) FROM Object A];

List<api-name-of-object-B> object_B_List = new List<api-name-of-object-B>();

for(api-name-of-object-A object_A : object_A_List) {
     // all the field values need to moved manually with proper field mapping
}

insert object_B_List;
```